# Convert decimal number to binary number and change one index

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I am looking for the fastest solution of the following problem:
My function takes a decimal number `dec` and then converts it to a binary number `bin` of length `l`. Afterwards I change the value at the `i`'th index of the binary number and convert the result back to a decimal number. Currently I implemented this in the following way:

```
def new_dec_function(dec, i, l):
    bin = list(map(int, numpy.binary_repr(dec, width=l)))
    bin[i] = 1 - bin[i]
    new_dec = 0
    for bit in bin:
        new_dec = (new_dec << 1) | bit
    return new_dec
```

Do you know if this can be improved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'decimal' number you speak of is already stored in binary representation in your computer, so all you have to do is flip the i'th bit of the number. This can be easily accomplished with the binary xor operator `^`

```
def new_dec_function(dec, i):
    return dec ^ (1 << i)

>>> new_dec_function(5, 1)
7
>>> new_dec_function(5, 0)
4
```